# fopen(): SSL: Connection reset by peer error in php

Tags: php, curl, ssl, libcurl, fopen

I'm trying to download a report from my bing ads account and i'm encountering the following errors:
Warning: fopen(): SSL: Connection reset by peer in xxxx...
Warning: fopen(): Failed to enable crypto in xxx...

```
      function PollGenerateReport($proxy, $reportRequestId)
      {
         // Set the request information.

         $request = new PollGenerateReportRequest();
         $request->ReportRequestId = $reportRequestId;

         return $proxy->GetService()->PollGenerateReport($request)->ReportRequestStatus;
         return $proxy->GetService()->PollGenerateReport($request)>ReportRequestStatus;
       }

      // Using the URL that the PollGenerateReport operation returned,
      // send an HTTP request to get the report and write it to the specified
      // ZIP file.
      function DownloadFile($reportDownloadUrl, $downloadPath)
      {
          if (!$reader = fopen($reportDownloadUrl, 'rb'))
           {
               throw new Exception("Failed to open URL " . $reportDownloadUrl . ".");
           }
           if (!$writer = fopen($downloadPath, 'wb'))
           {
               fclose($reader);
               throw new Exception("Failed to create ZIP file " . $downloadPath . ".");
            }
            $bufferSize = 100 * 1024;

            while (!feof($reader))
            {
                if (false === ($buffer = fread       ($reader, $bufferSize)))
                 {
                    fclose($reader);
                    fclose($writer);
                    throw new Exception("Read operation from URL failed.");
                 }
                 if (fwrite($writer, $buffer) === false)
                 {
                     fclose($reader);
                     fclose($writer);
                     $exception = new Exception("Write operation to ZIP file failed.");
                 }
              }
                 fclose($reader);
                 fflush($writer);
                 fclose($writer);
         }
```

Since i'm a newbie to php, i'm asking for any assistance/tipps on how to convert the fopen() function (which from research seems to be the problem here) to curl. I'm using the bing API to download the report and running the script on a server.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first idea is that the URL might be password protected?

If it is possible it would be better to export the report and then import it on your server.

Alternatively see if BING has documentation on how to access their reports externally, is there an API (Application Protocol Interface)?

Comment: I'm already using the Bing API for this and i have passed on the necessary credentials (username, password). What does SSL have to do with it?

Comment: You haven't said anything about an API and credentials in your question. It sounds like you're just logging in with your browser? Please consider the fact that your browser is not your server. If you log in with your webbrowser, the credentials are 'stored' in that program. Your PHP webserver does not have access to them. From the point of view of the BING server it's just a new client.

Comment: Fair enough. I'm running the script that contains the user credentials on a server though.

Comment: If that's a PHP script, and it creates a secured connection to the BING server, then that, and only that, connection will work. You cannot just use fopen() and create a completely new connection without any credentials. Such a connection will be refused.

Comment: @KIKI Software. Thanks mate. You were right on the first account. I didnt have sufficient rights for the downloadURL. Got it fixed.